# Redis JsonJacksonCodec. Problem with LocalDateTime serialization

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, redis, jackson

I am using Spring Boot 2, Redis server v=5.0.9, Java 14.
I am trying to save object, which contains LocalDateTime field to RMap and getting next error:

> "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Expected
>   array or string."

Config for Redis:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
             .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
             .modules(new JSR310Module())
             .build();
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:6379");
config.setCodec(new JsonJacksonCodec(mapper));
```

And field:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
```

Tried different options from google - nothing worked.

Really need your help!

Comment: Should not you be using `JavaTimeModule` instead of deprecated `JSR310Module`?  You may also need to check answers to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527794/how-do-i-configure-jackson-serialization-on-localdatetime-and-localdate-for-java/51546069).

Comment: Hi @AlexRudenko . Tried JavaTimeModule - same result. Also i tried a lot of options from similar questions - nothing worked. I will try all answers from link you offered. Hope it will help. Thank you.